# How can I send message to specific contact through WhatsApp from my ios app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, whatsapp

```
        // 1
        let urlWhats = "https://wa.me/\(mobile)/?text=\(text)"
        // 2
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
          // 3
          if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            // 4
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
              // 5
              UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
//                UIApplication.shared.\
            } else {
              // 6
              print("Cannot Open Whatsapp")
            }
          }
        }
```

I'm able to launch whatsapp from my app from the above mentioned code, it is composing prefix text to the contact I wish to send and I need to click the send button in whatsapp manually . But I'm looking for a code which automatically sends whatsapp text to number from my app. Can anyone share your thoughts on this?

Comment: you cannot automatically send whatsapp messages from code without user interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can only compose the message for a particular contact using the `Deep Linking` method that you have used for it. For sending the message user has to click on the send button manually. You could provide the user with an alert that says so. But, it's not possible to do it for the user from your side. If you were able to send a message on Whatsapp by writing code without the user's confirmation it would be a break of user's privacy. Don't you think?